# Server configuration for WordPress - Do I need install PHP-SSH extensions for Wordpress on Fedora28?

Tags: plugins, php, apache, ssh

**Migrated from Stackoverflow & Unix & Linux:**

Recently I tried to setup a **Wordpress** server on **Fedora28** based droplet on **Digital Ocean**.
A followed some tutorials and the result was the same: After a "successful" `Wordpress` installation **I couldn't add new plugins** etc.
Followed some resolving methods(debug, tutorials etc.), I found that it could be something about the unsuccessful **SSH connection** between Wordpress app and Wordpress.org.

Then in a tutorial a read the following, which is for `Ubuntu` and for older version PHP, but I found intresting:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-gd libssh2-php
```

> This will allow you to work with images and will also allow you to
>   install plugins and update portions of your site using your SSH login
>   credentials.

**My question is:**
Is there really something about some missing parts of php-ssh installation or I failed at some other part of configuring the LAMP/Wordpress environment?

Thank you!

**Update:**

I managed to find and installed the appropriate library for Fedora28: [see how](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457663/how-can-i-install-ssh-php-library-similar-to-ubuntus-libssh2-php-on-fedora28/457679#457679)
But the root of the problem has not been solved with it, since I have no **add new plugin** possibility in Wordpress dashboard still.

Comment: try this code in a single file `<?php echo file_get_contents("https://secure.php.net/file_get_contents");` if you don't see the PHP manual, look the error message.

Comment: I did what you proposed and got the `File not found.`.

Comment: @mmm does it mean something useful for you?

Comment: which file ? what is the complete error message ?

Comment: @mmm This is the complete error message.

Comment: @mmm Maybe I misinterpreted what you said, but I made a single file in /var/www/html dir as test.php and place the above code in that you wrote, then tried to access the IP.